# I need to convert an array of arrays into an arrays of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, arrayofarrays

I am trying to convert an array of arrays into an array of objects, I am working with Angular and TypeScript, this is the code:

```
look(data: [][]){
    
    const found = data.flatMap( element => element ).find(element => element == this.codigo );
    console.log(found);

    const dataobj = data.map(function(row){
      return {
        a: row[0],
        b: row[1],
        c: row[2],
        d: row[3],
        e: row[4],
        f: row[5],
        g: row[6],
      }
    });
    console.log(dataobj);
    console.log(this.datos);
    

  }
```

And I am getting this error:
src/app/hojaexcel/hojaexcel.component.ts:61:16 - error TS2493: Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '0'.

61         a: row[0],
~

Comment: can you give us what your `data` and `found` variables are populated with?

Comment: you can also debug by doing a `console.log(row)` because I'm guessing your array of arrays has a null value or something similar.

Comment: data is an array of arrays that has strings, I get it from an excel file. Found is a variable that I am looking in the data array, that works fine, but I am trying to convert the array of arrays(data), into an array of objects, to use Angular Material and display that array in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `[]` is a tuple type and not an array type. You can have `[number]`, `[number, string]` etc... these are all tuple types. `[]` would be a tuple with no elements. `[][]` is a tuple of a tuple with no elements, literally `[[]]`.

You need to declare a type for it to be an array of an array. I'm not sure what `data` is supposed to be, but let's assume it is a number:

```
look(data: number[][]) {
```